# How to access custom QuerySet methods from the Manager of a ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-managers

I'm using Django [Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/) to make a higher API to interact with my database and keeping my code cleaner and more readable. But in case I have a `Foreignkey` relationship, I can't use the manager of the ForeignKey model. The queries are more complex as below, but I just simplified the example so, It can be easier to read and get the idea of the question:

**models.py:**

```py
class Community(models.Model):
    objects = CommunityManager()
    ...


class Inscription(models.Model):
    objects = InscriptionManager()

    ...
    community = models.ForeignKey("Community", related_name="inscriptions")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

**managers.py:**

```py
from datetime import date
from django.db import models


class InscriptionQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def by_day(self, day=date.today()):
        return self.filter(created_at__day=day)

    ... # more queries


class InscriptionManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return InscriptionQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def today(self):
        return self.get_query_set().by_day()

    ... # more queries


class CommunityQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def by_type(self, type):
        return self.filter(type=type)

    ... # more queries


class CommunityManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return OrganistaionQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def by_type(self, type):
        return self.get_query_set().by_type(type)

    ... # more queries
```

**Usage:**

```py
Inscription.objects.by_day() # return correctly all the inscriptions made today
Community.objects.by_type('type1') # return correctly all Communities that match
```

**Problem:** but here lies the problem

```py
community_b = Community.objects.get(id=12)
community_b.inscriptions.by_day() 
>>> AttributeError: 'ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'by_day'
```

***How can I fixe this. How to customize the manager to take in consideration the models relation.***

Comment: Can you try adding `use_for_related_fields = True` to your `InscriptionManager`? Check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#controlling-automatic-manager-types

Comment: Why do you have a `QuerySet` and a `Manager` for both models?

Comment: @RohitJain I tried this but still the same error. Yes it will be optimized to one manager, but now it just for clarity purpose I'm using manger for every model.

Comment: Still not sure why you've both managers and QuerySet, but can you move that method to `QuerySet`, and assign objects in your model to `InscriptionQuerySet.as_manager()`? I think that way, it should work. It works for me.

Comment: I did not get what method are you talking about. But since it works for you.I think it will be helpful to share it as an answer.

Comment: I see that your `by_day()` method is in `InscriptionQuerySet` already, but you're trying to access that on `InscriptionManager`. How does that work? What's that `AnreiseQuerySet` in your manager `get_query_set()` method?

Comment: ah okay, I just wrote it wrong, but it's correctly done in my code. I updated the post. How did you test it and works for you, would you please share it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need of both `Manager` and `QuerySet` in your approach. You could just do away with a `QuerySet`. This is how I generally implement custom managers, and I tried accessing custom manager method on reverse relationship in one of my projects, and it works fine:

```
class InscriptionQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def by_day(self, day=date.today()):
        return self.filter(created_at__day=day)

    def today(self):
        return self.by_day()

class CommunityQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def by_type(self, type):
        return self.filter(type=type)
```

And then in your models, change your `objects` like this:

```
class Community(models.Model):
    objects = CommunityQuerySet.as_manager()
    ...


class Inscription(models.Model):
    objects = InscriptionQuerySet.as_manager()
```

I think you would be able to access custom queryset method with this setup.

Comment: It works greatly for me. The approach I'm using is proposed here in the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager) and I don't know what's the difference between the two approaches. But thanks for the Tip.